# Tree ordering and upclosure and downclosure

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am referring Diestal book on Graph Theory($5^{th}$ Edition)

In section 1.5 defines the following :

Writing x $ < $ y for x ∈ rT y then defines a partial
ordering on V (T ), the tree-order associated with T and r. We shall
think of this ordering as expressing ‘height’: if x < y we say that x lies
below y in T , we call
$\lceil y \rceil$ := { x | x $\leq$ y } and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ := { y | y $\geq$ x }
the down-closure of y and the up-closure of x

I have a confusion with Lemma 1.5.5 of the Diestal book on Graph Theory($5^{th}$ Edition)which states that:

> Let T be a normal tree in G
>
> (i) Any two vertices x, y ∈ T are separated in G by the set $\lceil x \rceil ∩ \lceil y \rceil $.

My doubt is: how $\lceil x \rceil ∩ \lceil y \rceil $ separates x and y?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the definitions correctly? I'm having trouble seeing the difference between up-closure and down-closure. If $\lceil x\rceil:=\{y|y\le x\}$ is the up-closure of $x,$ what is the down-closure of $x?$

Comment: If $\lceil y\rceil$ is called the down-closure of $y,$ and $\lceil x\rceil$ is called the up-closure of $x,$ would $\lceil z\rceil$ be called the down-closure or the up-closure or $z?$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in  up-closure notation. Now it is corrected.

Comment: What is "rT y"?

Comment: rTy represents T is a rooted tree and it has a tree ordering (partial ordering on V(T)). That means root element *r* is the least element and all leaf nodes in the tree are maximal elements

Comment: On the last line, shouldn't $\lceil x\rceil\cap\lceil y\rceil$ be either $\lfloor x\rfloor\cap\lceil y\rceil$ or $\lceil x\rceil\cap\lfloor y\rfloor$?

Comment: The down-closure of $y$ is the set of all elements below $y,$ and the up-closure of $x$ is the set of all elements below $x$? Shouldn't the up-closure of $x$ be $\{y|y\ge x\},$ the set of all elements ***above*** $x?$

Comment: In the lemma it is given as  $\lceil x \rceil ∩ \lceil y \rceil $. The up-closure contains all elements above the x.

Comment: What is the definition of "$S$ separates $x$ and $y$"?

Comment: Separates x and y means,  the set  ⌈x⌉∩⌈y⌉ disconnect the element x and y in tree

Comment: You mention down-closure and up-closure in the title, but your final question $$\text{My doubt is how }\lceil x\rceil\cap\lceil y\rceil\text{ separates }x\text{ and }y?$$ involves only the down-closures  of $x$ and $y.$

Comment: @ bof  I got the point. In the definition rTy, each element in the tree keeps a partial ordering. So consider the root element as its least element an all leaves are the maximal element.  If x,y $\in$ V(T)  and take their down closure. In the set ⌈x⌉∩⌈y⌉ contains at-least root element, if we remove that root element, then x and y becomes disconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition V(T) keeps a partial ordering, is a tree order associated with root element **r** and tree **T**. So, consider the **r** as the least element and all leaves in the tree are the maximal elements.

Consider any two vertices x,y $\in$ V(T) and ⌈x⌉, ⌈y⌉. In each element down closure contains at least root element **r**(according to the definition of down closure ). If take their ⌈x⌉∩⌈y⌉ it also contains **r**. If we remove root element, it makes x and y disconnected.

Comment: Removing the root element doesn't necessarily disconnect $x$ and $y$, but $\lceil x\rceil \cap \lceil y \rceil$ also contains whatever the least element on the path from $x$ to $y$ is, even when that's not the root.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I forgot to specify other least elements. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If x = y, that set includes x and y.
If x < y, that set excludes y, includes x.
In both cases, thought usually disconnecting
T, removal of that set isn't a x,y separation.

If x,y are incomparabled, that set is the
lower set of inf{x,y} which includes r.
Removal of that set disconnects T, leaving
x in one part, y in another, a separation.

Apparently, the definition applies
only to incomparable vertices.